# Медленный IntelliSense для C++ в VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Я пользовался ***VS Code*** для того, чтоб писать код на `Python`, решил перейти на **`C++`** , однако использовал я на этот раз **Sublime text 3**. Решил вернуться в VS Code, подключил `gcc-x64 (legacy)` как компилятор, скачал **C/C++ Extension Pack**, был уже готов, но...

> IntelliSense от VSCode был очень медленным

Я решил проверить IntelliSense на `Python`, `C`, все было хорошо, а в ***C++*** все было печально. Только очень маленькие программы давали подсазки за 0.5-1 секунду. А код в 50 **строк уже искал 3-5 секунд...** Как это исправить?

Comment: Стандартный плагин для C/C++ - в мусор, и вместо него поставить Clangd. Он должен работать быстрее.

Comment: Скоро попробую. Заранее спасибо за ответ) А что еще делает этот плагин помимо автозаполнения и тем?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , я установил, но при заполнении там зачеркнутый текст, почему?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, достаточно снести `C/C++`, а `C/C++ Themes` можно оставить. Хотя непонятно, будет ли он работать. По идее, Clangd делает все то же самое, минус поддержка отладчика. Для нее нужно ставить отдельный плагин (`CodeLLDB`, `Native Debug`, или что-то еще).

Comment: *"зачеркнутый текст"* Скриншот покажите.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , сейчас эта ерунда пропала. Большое вам спасибо! Это расширение не только работает со скоростью света, а также добавляет что-то: если написать `for`, то он составит _полный цикл for с всеми тремя указаниями_, при использовании `#include` он еще поставит угловые скобки, и так далее. Большое вам спасибо)))